# Проблема с памятью в приложении java на centOS

Tags: java, centos, opencv, spring-boot, утечка-памяти

Добрый день! Такая проблема:
Есть spring-boot(1.5.8.RELEASE) rest service, который использует библиотеку openCV(org.openpnp:opencv:3.2.0-1).

Тест на windows 7 (x64, Intel Xeon E5-2698, RAM 16Gb, java oracle build 1.8.0_121-b13), параметры запуска: java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms100M -Xmx1G -jar image.math.process.service.jar --server.port=8082
Когда запустилось занимает ~450Mb ОЗУ, выполняем рест запрос использование ОЗУ вырастает до ~1200Mb, после чистится до ~450Mb - всё норм.

Тест на centoOS 7 (x64, Intel Xeon E5-2630, RAM 8Gb, java oracle build 1.8.0_161-b12), параметры запуска: java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms100M -Xmx1G -jar image.math.process.service.jar --server.port=8082
Когда запустилось занимает ~800Mb ОЗУ, выполняем рест запрос использование ОЗУ вырастает до ~3,5Gb, после, не очищается и забивается вся ОЗУ, потом машина фризит.

Почему так происходит?

P.S. пробовали разные сборщики мусора, разные ограничения памяти, такое ощущение, что сборщик просто не работает, не работает и jcmd  GC.run, такое же поведение и на openJDK

Comment: На каждый запрос по ~1-3 гб памяти выделяется? O.o

Comment: Да, графическая обработка изображений

Comment: Я, конечно, не уверен, но это слишком много, разве нет? Как вы собираетесь наладить работу сервера? Он будет один запрос в минуту принимать, или же вы у NASA сервера арендуете?)

Comment: Проект у нас пилотный, да памяти много, но нас сейчас интересует максимальная скорость и что мы за это заплатил. А столкнулись с проблемой на centOS, и нужно её решить